# F# :: traversing lists There and Back Again

Tags: list, f#, functional-programming, traversal

*Write a function that counts the number of elements in the list that are larger than or equal to the average (using integer division for simplicity).*
***Using just a `single traversal` of the list structure!***

---

I already have a solution to this, BUT it involves `ref` variable changed from closure `foo'`.

I'm interested in a way **how to** ***functionally*** **pass value when `[]` is met**?

---

My naïve solution using `ref`:

```
let foo ls =
    let avg = ref 0
    let rec foo' xs sumAcc lenAcc  =
        match xs with
        | x'::xs'   ->
            let s = foo' xs' (x' + sumAcc) (1 + lenAcc)
            if x' < !avg then s else s + 1
        | []        ->
            avg := (sumAcc / lenAcc) //? how to change THIS to functional code ?
            0
    foo' ls 0 0
```

---

---

**EDIT**(3)**:**

I was interested in performance...
on `list [1..11000]`

```
`(my solution with REF) 5501: elapsed <00.0108708>`  
`(nlucaroni)            5501: elapsed <00.0041484>`  
`(kvb)                  5501: elapsed <00.0029200>`  <-- continuation is fastest
`(two pass solution)    5501: elapsed <00.0038364>`
```

since **1.** and **3.** solutions are non-tail-recursive,

---

```
// simple two-pass solution
let foo2pass (xs : System.Numerics.BigInteger list) =
    let len = System.Numerics.BigInteger.Parse(xs.Length.ToString())
    let avg = List.sum xs / len
    (List.filter (fun x -> x >= avg) xs).Length
```

---

***two pass*** and ***kvb***'s version works on big lists, ie: `list [1I .. 10 000 000I]`:

```
(two-pass solution)   5000001: elapsed <00:00:12.3200438>     <-- 12 first time
(two-pass solution)   5000001: elapsed <00:00:06.7956307>     <-- 6
(two-pass solution)   5000001: elapsed <00:00:09.1390587>     <-- 9? WHY IS THAT
(two-pass solution)   5000001: elapsed <00:00:06.8345791>     <-- 6
(two-pass solution)   5000001: elapsed <00:00:09.1071856>     <-- 9? WHY IS THAT
```

5 times for each solution

```
(kvb tail-recursive) 5000001I: elapsed <00:00:21.1825866>   <-- 21 first time
(kvb tail-recursive) 5000001I: elapsed <00:00:14.8113939>   <-- stable
(kvb tail-recursive) 5000001I: elapsed <00:00:14.8335997>
(kvb tail-recursive) 5000001I: elapsed <00:00:14.8418234>
(kvb tail-recursive) 5000001I: elapsed <00:00:14.8331327>
```

and for `list [1I .. 1 000 000I]`, *kvb*'s solution is faster

```
(two-pass solution) 500001I: elapsed <00:00:01.8975782>
(kvb tail-recursive) 500001: elapsed <00:00:00.6004453>
```

Comment: Just a note in passing: All the implementations here seem to involve copying the whole list (to a chain of activation records or lambdas), then traversing the copy backwards. In practice, I think you'd be better off just traversing the list twice.

Comment: I'm curious: What school do you go to? I'm pleasantly surprised that there are courses where you can use F#.

Comment: @bcat I have my doubts about the value of the "single traversal" exercise, however. I really hope that lesson two is benchmarking lesson one's solutions against the obvious implementation that does traverse the list twice, and drawing the natural conclusions.

Comment: @Pascal: Agreed. Actually, I think you could make a reasonable argument that *all* solutions to this problem will traverse the list at least twice. In nlucaroni's answer, for example, the list is first traversed forwards to calculate the average. Then, as the stack unwinds, each element is reexamined to calculate the desired count. Each element is visited twice, so it's really doing two traversals, IMO. kvb's answer does something very similar. The implicit stack use is repalced by continution-passing, but it's still visiting each element two times.

Comment: Which is basically what Jason said. I need to learn how to read, I guess. :)

Comment: @bcat: It's Charles University, Prague, Europe. And basically there is this course because Tomáš Peříček teaches it. :-) (worked with Don Syme, F# intern @MS)

Comment: Was the title a deliberate reference to the following rather relevant paper?
http://www.brics.dk/RS/05/Abs/BRICS-RS-05-Abs/BRICS-RS-05-Abs.html#BRICS-RS-05-3

Comment: @Ganesh: Title was not accidental, but I didn't know *that* TABA paper. Thanks for reference, Ganesh. :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just need to pass the average up the stack with the return value:

```
let foo ls =
    let rec foo xs sumAcc lenAcc  = match xs with
        | x::xs -> let avg,s = foo xs (x + sumAcc) (1 + lenAcc) in
                   if x < avg then (avg,s) else (avg,s+1)
        | []    -> (sumAcc / lenAcc),0
    in
    let avg,res = foo ls 0 0 in
    res
```

Comment: +1: took me a few moments to figure out what you're doing there, but its actually pretty clever :)

Comment: Assuming the OP is using light syntax, you can drop the `in` keywords to make things a bit cleaner.

Comment: #light? *shiver*, no thanks. Call me formal but that `in` means something in the readability of the code.

Answer (score 7):

Here's another option:

```
let foo =
  let rec helper sum ct getCt = function
  | x::xs -> 
      helper (sum+x) (ct+1) (fun avg -> getCt(avg) + (if avg <= x then 1 else 0)) xs
  | [] -> getCt(sum/ct)
  helper 0 0 (fun avg -> 0)
```

To help clarify what's going on here, I'll describe the parameters for the helper function:

- sum: the sum of all items seen so far
- ct: the count of all items seen so far
- getCt: a function taking a single parameter and which returns the tally of the number of items seen so far which are at least as large as that parameter
- the final list parameter which is pattern matched

  - if it's empty, then calculate the average of all items by dividing the total by the count, and then pass this to the `getCt` function to determine how many items were greater than it.
  - otherwise, recurse into the tail of the list, passing in an updated total and count.  The new `getCt` function should call the previous `getCt` function to see how many items prior to this one are greater than the average, and then increment that total if this item was also greater.

It's also possible to create a modified version that uses only tail calls, so it won't cause a stack overflow even on lists of arbitrary size.  To do this, our `getCt` function now needs an accumulator parameter representing the count so far:

```
let foo =
  let rec helper sum ct getCt = function
  | x::xs -> 
      helper (sum+x) (ct+1) (fun avg n -> getCt avg (if avg <= x then n+1 else n)) xs
  | [] -> getCt (sum/ct) 0
  helper 0 0 (fun avg n -> n)
```

Comment: +1: continuation passing occasionally makes people claw their eyes out, but this example is particularly easy to read.

Comment: +1: I've only misty idea how that works... But like it. Can You elaborate, please? This is interesting!

Comment: +100 Thank You, I didn't know that before. I can imagine lot of another cases where this is usefull.

Comment: @DinGODzilla: Really?  I can run `foo [1 .. 10000000]` and get a result (which exhibits arithmetic overflow, but that's a different issue), and when I try `foo [1 .. 100000000]` I get an out of memory exception, not a stack overflow...

Comment: @kvb: Oddly, in Visual Studio it overflows even on `[1 .. 12000]`, but in FSI it just works.. :-/ No idea why, but will test it in FSI. Thanks kvb!

Comment: @DinGODzilla: Check your Visual Studio project options and make sure tail calls are enabled. I believe they're not in the default debug configuration.

Comment: @DinGODzilla: most likely the out-of-memory exception results because you're using [1 .. 100000000], not because of the kvb's code. Remember, [ n .. m ] constructs all the elements in a list on demand, so a list of 100,000,000 integers consumes 4 bytes per integer + 4 bytes per Cons pointer + 4 bytes per tail pointer. So, you're looking at around 12 bytes per element, or around 1.1 GB of memory *just to construct the list*.

Answer (score 0):

Haskell's lazy evaluation really shines in "tying the knot":

```
avgList t = let (final, sum, count) = go t 0 0 0
                avg = sum `div` count
                go [] finalA sumA countA = (finalA, sumA, countA)
                go (x:xs) finalA sumA countA = go xs (x' + finalA) (sumA + x) (countA + 1)
                    where x' = if x >= avg then 1 else 0
            in final
```